# How to write a regular expression for every string w over {0,1} where w is a binary string with value of at least 40.

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, computational-mathematics, regular-language, regular-expressions

So far I have realized that minimum value is `101000` in binary, but we also have to accept strings like `110000` and `1000000`.

I came up with

```
r = (0+1)^* 1 (01+10+11) (0+1)^3
```

but then realized the string could also be `10000000`. I'm not sure how to take into consideration that any 1's after the six digit from the left will also take the value over $40$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will leave writing the regex to you, but I would write a regex that checks two things:

- If the number is $101$, $110$ or $111$, followed by any three characters, then match.
- If the number is $1$, followed by any $6$ characters, followed by any number (including zero) of other characters then match.

Otherwise, do not match.

The first condition matches all numbers from `101000` (that is, $40$) to `111111` (that is, $63$).

The second conditions matches all numbers, greater than `1000000` (that is, $64$.

---

Note that you might want to also consider if you want to handle leading zeroes, but that shouldn't make it much harder.

Comment: Hi thanks for that. What about the case where the number is 1 followed by 7 characters... This is where I am having trouble. For example what you recommended would work for 101000 and 1000000 and 1000001 but not 10000000. Im not sure how to accept any 1 before 6 characters

Comment: @ryansl39 Yeah, my second condition was wrong, I was sloppy. I replaced it. You can match "zero or more repetitions" in regex, so that is what you should do.

Comment: Oh I see. Many thanks, I will have a go at that.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Have upvoted but dont have enough rep yet for it to show

Answer (score 2):

Even if you can't think of anything clever, you could do something brute-force.  Suppose $A$ was a regex that matched all the numbers that are at least 64.  That might  not be too hard to come up with. Then you could do $$\mathtt{101000} + \mathtt{101001} + \cdots +\mathtt{111111} + A.$$

Comment: That's a good way to look at it. Thank you